# Chance of duplicate records in hive

Tags: hive

I have table structure like `date_created`, value created in hive with partition column as `date_created`. Data in the table as of now is

```
Date_created , value

Jan,            a

Jan,            b

Jan,            c

Jan,            a
```

If this data is loaded into hive table in `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE PARTITION (date_created)` format , will the table contain two records for "Jan , a" ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you execute the below statements four times,

```
Insert Overwrite partition (date_created='Jan') select ....;
```

or

```
Load data inpath '/hdfs/path/file' overwrite into table <table_name> partition(date_created='Jan');
```

you will have the final set of values loaded into the partition i.e. values/file loaded into the partition during the first load will be overwritten by the second load and 3rd load will erase 2nd load and so on...

So, as per your values, the partition (date_created=Jan) will have only one record with value 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your table will have two records for (Jan, a) as your file has two records for (Jan, a) provided your query doesn't has any filtering or distinct clause.

Comment: Its insert overwrite, and Jan partition is loade multiple times..can you explain why will it have duplicates

Comment: insert overwrite doesn't mean that it will remove duplicates.
It will delete all existing records from current partition and re-insert the data. But since your data has same record twice it will be added to the partition

Comment: Take a re-look at the data. Partition column is - 'Date_created' & the value 'Jan' is present multiple times in his data. So, each time it will be reloaded